# How do use RTE_ConvertTextAreaToRichEdit() function in a customized aspx page in SharePoint 2007

Tags: 2007, textarea

How do use RTE_ConvertTextAreaToRichEdit() function in a customized aspx page in SharePoint 2007?

I tried using a Javascript cleditor together with SPServices but could not get my data inside the rich text box to be store into the multi-lines text field inside a list.

Below are javascript code that I tried for reference only:

**CODE A - cleditor**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#newWordDesc").cleditor();
});
```

**CODE B - SPservices**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        CreateNewItem($("#newWordDesc").val());

        function CreateNewItem(newWordDesc) {
            $().SPServices({
                operation: "UpdateListItems",
                async: false,
                batchCmd: "New",
                listName: "MyList",
                valuepairs: [["Description", newWordDesc]],
                completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
                   $("#responseStatus").html(Status);
                   $("#responseXML").text(xData.responseXML.xml);

                }
            });
        }
```

**CODE C - HTML TextArea using Javascript**

```
document.write('<textarea id="newWordDesc" wrap="soft"></textarea>');
```

Would appreciate if any insight provided.

**Update (Based on Amit)**

I modify Amit's code as follows and the RTE is now displayed correctly. (However, if one enter data into the RTE field, and submit into a SharePoint List via SPServices, it will not work.)

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/_layouts/1033/form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //To determine if browser is IE
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (browseris.ie5up && browseris.win32 && !IsAccessibilityFeatureEnabled())
    {
    RTE_ConvertTextAreaToRichEdit("newWordDesc", true, false, "", "1033", null, null, null, null, null,"FullHtml", "\u002f",null,null,null,null);
    } 
    // else render help link if browser is Non-IE i.e. chrome,firefox etc
    else
    {
    document.write("&nbsp;<br><SPAN class=ms-formdescription><a href='javascript:HelpWindowKey(\"nsfullrichtext\")'>Click for help about adding HTML formatting.</a></SPAN>&nbsp;<br>");
    };
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The function is defined in

> /_layouts/1033/form.js

and its signature looks like :

```
function RTE_ConvertTextAreaToRichEdit(
            strBaseElementID,
            fRestrictedMode,
            fAllowHyperlink,
            strDirection,
            strWebLocale,
            fSimpleTextOnly,
            fEditable,
            fUseDynamicHeightSizing,
            iMaxHeightSize,
            iMinHeightSize,
            strMode,
            urlWebRoot,
            strThemeUrl,
            strBodyClassName,
            fAllowRelativeLinks,
            strBaseUrl,
            fUseDynamicWidthSizing,
            iMaxWidthSize,
            iMinWidthSize,
            fEnforceAccessibilityMode,
            fPreserveScript,
            fHookUpEvents,
            fGenerateToolbar
            )
{....}
```

In the form,You can use it like :

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/_layouts/1033/form.js"></script>
<script>
    //To determine if browser is IE
    if (browseris.ie5up && browseris.win32 && !IsAccessibilityFeatureEnabled())
    {
    RTE_ConvertTextAreaToRichEdit("<<Insert your TextField client Id>>", true, false, "", "1033", null, null, null, null, null,"FullHtml", "\u002f",null,null,null,null);
    } 
    // else render help link if browser is Non-IE i.e. chrome,firefox etc
    else
    {
    document.write("&nbsp;<br><SPAN class=ms-formdescription><a href='javascript:HelpWindowKey(\"nsfullrichtext\")'>Click for help about adding HTML formatting.</a></SPAN>&nbsp;<br>");
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Strange, it give me a error `SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'innerText': object is null or undefined` point to the file `form.js, line 734 character 2`. (For your info, my textarea is `<textarea id="newWordDesc"></textarea>`)

Comment: Hi Amit, Thanks, made some modification to your code and now it is working. However, I still could not get the data, which I typed inside this RTE text field into SharePoint 2007 via SPServices. Any Insight?